# How do you use 附近的 in a sentence? Also, 所有的？

Tags: meaning, usage, difference

I am learning Chinese, and I was confused on how to use the previously mentioned phrases in a sentence. Is it possible that someone could put them into a basic sentence so I could get a basic understanding of the two phrases? Thanks!

Also, what is the difference between: 比, 比较, and 较?  How would you use them in a sentence?

I do not have a certain context in mind, anything works! (It would be nice to have the sentences short, since it would be a lot easier for me to understand.

Thank you very much!　
谢谢！

Comment: There are many usages for these words, do you have a specific context in mind?

Comment: Can you narrow your question down a bit? As it stands, your title has no relation to the body of the question.

Answer (score 4):

`附近的` , `所有的` are adjectives.

- `附近的` common usage: `附近的`+{Object} , means {Object} is near.
- `所有的` common usage: `所有的`+{Object} , means all {Object}.

Example：

> **附近的**建筑非常漂亮。
>   Nearby buildings are very beautiful.
>
> 附近**所有的**建筑都非常漂亮。
>   All nearby buildings are very beautiful.

[比](https://www.moedict.tw/%E6%AF%94)，[比较](https://www.moedict.tw/%E6%AF%94%E8%BC%83)，[较](https://www.moedict.tw/%E8%BC%83) they all have the meaning `To compare,To contrast` . Their usage are very complex. Let me just show some examples.

> 我比你高
>   I am taller than you.
>
> 和你家比较，我家更大。
>   To compare with your house, my house is bigger.

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% sure with what you are asking for but let me try with the things right off my head.

"附近的" can only be used to mean that somehow physically near by, and it is not used to measure something past in time -- "刚才的" is used to measure the past time. 
Example: 你刚才说的我听不懂。

比   -- to compare. 
Example: 你的英语比我好(Your English is better than mine). 比一比，看谁比较重（To compare it, Let use see whom is relatively heavier) Please notice I put a "比较" here.

比较 -- to compare, or relatively, or to some degree. 
Example for comparision: 比较下来，我还是最喜欢stackexchange.(After some comparison, I decided that I liked StackExchange best.
Example for relatively: 我比较喜欢吃水果. (I prefer fruits). Please notice the degree of preference here is not that strong, just a slightly inclined intention).

较   -- sometime this is used as a shorten form of 比较. This is not commonly used compared with 比较. 
Example: 我比较喜欢两个女人中胸部较大的那个(Among these two women, I prefer the one with bigger boobs). Please note that here again I gave the example of 比较. And if you replace the 较 with 比较, it is 100% ok except a little bit of tendentious.

Answer (score 1):

I am a chinese and i will give you a few examples below:

1. 附近的超市真多 means There are lots of supermarket nearby
2. 所有的人请站起来 means Everyone please stand up
3. 我所有的朋友都住在附近 means All of my friends are living nearby me

2.比, 比较, and 较

1. 我比你矮 means I am shorter then you
2. 我最近比较忙 means I am so busy recently

较 Generally speaking, this word usually combine with "比" , so i can't memory any sentence with a single 较
比：usually use in a comparison while "比较" usually means relatively, rather, fairl or quite.

Comment: 较 is typically used in `较...而...` and `较...更...`. For example, `较这种苹果而言, 我更喜欢那种苹果` and `这种苹果较那种苹果更甜`. It's fine to replace `较` with `比` in the second sentence, `较` sounds more formal.

Answer (score 0):

附近的 and 所有的 can both function as adjectives.  So 附近的+Noun would be "the neighboring/nearby Noun" and 所有的+Noun would be "all the Noun."  As for 比, 比较, and 较, I suggest looking them up in a good dictionary (many people like http://www.zdic.net as an online dictionary) and reading the explanations given for each, paying careful attention to the different grammatical functions of each.  Then, if you have a specific question based on what you have learned, you will probably be able to get a useful answer here.